# How to know which thread crashed the application?

Tags: visual-c++, crash-reports

I've developed VC++ application which runs fine on my laptop but crashes on a server PC. This is error message I receive:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name:   Terminator.exe
    Application Version:    0.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp:  53e0fcee
    Fault Module Name:  Terminator.exe
    Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
    Fault Module Timestamp: 53e0fcee
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Offset:   000000000000e79c
    OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
    Locale ID:  1033
    Additional Information 1:   62f5
    Additional Information 2:   62f5297269af48d65377b01a2aee9b2d
    Additional Information 3:   1ec0
    Additional Information 4:   1ec0dd9dc74b0802a47c92d98c459c66

    Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

In console this message was shown:

> Cause: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Attempted to read from: 0x00000000

Likely somehow I access wrong pointer or doing something outside array range or something like that. To further diagnose this problem I want to know which exact application **thread** causes exception. Knowing thread I can add line-by-line tracing and then find exact problem line.

Can I know somehow which thread crashed application? (Ideally inside my application can I name each thread and then force application to display name of the crashed thread.)

Comment: Try this link for a Dr. Watson replacement.  It might give you the info you want:  

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2010/12/29/drwtsn32-on-windows-vista-windows-server-2008-windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: Do you have access to the .dmp (Crash Dump) file that's associated with that crash?

Comment: @rrirower i can't find any *.dmp files on entire filesystem

Comment: If you can recreate the crash, AND, you feel comfortable updating registry keys, you can trap the crash dump file using the [WER registry settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638(v=vs.85).aspx).  In particular, the "LocalDumps\[Application Name]\DumpFolder" key specifies where to save the crash dump file locally.

Comment: @rrirower in registry i don't have such directory as "LocalDumps". probably I should create it? does it mean that by default Windows Server 2008 R2 does NOT create dumps?

Comment: and still it's interesting if I can solve this problem without dump file at all. Why Windows just don't print name of the fault process?

Comment: If you want to trap the dump locally, you need to use those settings.  Once you have a crash dump file, debugging should be easier assuming you have debug symbols available for your program.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy on my computer "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\" doesn't contain "LocalDumps" subfolder. should I create subfolder myself?

Comment: i created these keys now I have .dmp 200 Megabytes file and I also have small .wer file. Could you please suggest what should I do next?

Comment: I just opened .dmp file in Visual Studio, Start debugging, and it showed me exact line where exception occured. So it seems my problem is solved now.

Comment: How to force Windows 8.1 to create .dmp files when application crashes? I've tried to create same registry keys but this doesn't help.